# Differences in texlive implementations

Tags: texlive, pdftex, ubuntu

I run the same input file in two computers, one having TeX Live/Debian under Ubuntu, the 
other with TeX Live/opensuse under SUSE 11.1. 
The second one fails to handle the file properly. In particular, it cannot resolve 
references of type `\ref{label}` in the list of figures and (probably therefore) it cannot
break lines properly. Reading the log-files I just notice that pdfTeX under SUSE loads 
many additional packages not loaded by the Ubuntu distribution.
Questions:
Have you seen similar problems before? Anywhere I could read to get advice?
How can I control which packages should pdftex load within each distribution?

Answer (score 13):

Chances are high both distributions are using different versions of texlive with different versions of included packages, you can find the exact packages and versions by adding `\listfiles` to your preamble and comparing the output of both installation.